# Как пользоваться GULP + Yarn?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, yarn

Я учусь, мне дано задание сверстать сайт при помощи GULP. Сборка использовалась эта: https://github.com/andreyalexeich/gulp-scss-starter 
 Я всё установила по инструкции, а оно не работает. В процессе установки на стадии "скачайте необходимые зависимости: yarn" стали выскакивать какие-то gyp error.
Потом при попытке начать режим разработки yarn run dev сервер не запускается и консоль выдаёт тонну всякой ахинеи.
Можно ли устранить как-то эти проблемы? Или мне стоит поискать другую сборку?

Comment: Вам стоит вчитаться в **тонну всякой ахинеи**. Она там не просто так, она несет полезную информацию. Желательно также разобраться, что там за **какие-то gyp error**.

Comment: Если Вы думаете, что я в этих ошибках разбираюсь, тоо Вы напрасно так думаете. Я новичок в фронтенде, я ещё "маленькая". Сборку GULP использовала эту: http://tpverstak.ru/gulp/ ставила, естественно по приведённой инструкции. Yarn и NodeJS поставлены загодя. А т.к. весь текст в комментарий не помещается, я вставила его в документ, ссылка на него: https://github.com/Nimfeechka/Error

Comment: Вы же учитесь, значит надо учиться. Вставьте сообщения об ошибках непосредственно в вопрос. Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1114895/edit)